# Highchart: incorrect candle chart for day saving time DST

Tags: highcharts

DST hour 2:00 to 3:00 is not rending fine on highchart. I have below data.

```
    [new Date('2017/03/12 01:00:00').getTime(), 10],
    [new Date('2017/03/12 02:00:00').getTime(), 20],
    [new Date('2017/03/12 03:00:00').getTime(), 30],
    [new Date('2017/03/12 04:00:00').getTime(), 40],
    [new Date('2017/03/12 05:00:00').getTime(), 50]
```

Check fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/SurenderK/ko8dk2fd/4/

[image]

Comment: I looks like it renders fine. API Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global.useUTC.

Comment: It's not that it's rendering wrong - it's that your call to `getTime()` is returning the same value for 2:00 and 3:00: `1489302000000`. I don't know why that is, but it works the same regardless of the `useUTC` setting. http://jsfiddle.net/ko8dk2fd/5/

Comment: It is the same value because at 3:00 the daylight savings is done and the clock is turned back to 2:00.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this. Issue was with the ordinate we are sending. as new Date() is covering 2:00 and 3:00 to the same time for DST. So we need to send right ordinates in milliseconds itself.

I used a function convertInMill  that will convert time string to UTC and add timezone offset back.

```
var convertInMill = function(stringDate) {
  var obj, year, mnth, day, hr, min, sec, timeZoneOffset, timeInMillS;

  timeZoneOffset = 1; // machine timezone offset with UTC timezone

  obj = stringDate.split(/[\s/:-]+/);
  year = obj[0];
  mnth = obj[1];
  day = obj[2];
  hr = obj[3];
  min = obj[4];
  sec = obj[5];

  timeInMillS = Date.UTC(year, mnth - 1, day, hr, min, sec) + (timeZoneOffset * 3600000);

  return timeInMillS;
}
```

Series date

```
series: [{
  data: [
    [convertInMill('2017/03/12 00:00:00'), 10],
    [convertInMill('2017/03/12 01:00:00'), 20],
    [convertInMill('2017/03/12 02:00:00'), 30],
    [convertInMill('2017/03/12 03:00:00'), 40],
    [convertInMill('2017/03/12 04:00:00'), 50]
  ]
}]``
```

Below fiddle is working fine for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/SurenderK/ko8dk2fd/11/